# What's the thing you would consider because <it> is so important when you buy a computer?

Tags: sentence-construction

Here's the sentence in my textbook.

What's the most important thing you would consider when you buy a computer?

But, what if I start the sentence with "What's the thing.."

Can I say like..

> 1. What's the thing you think is so important you would consider when you buy a computer?
> 2. What's the thing you would consider because is so important when you buy a computer?
> 3. What's the thing you would consider because ***it*** is so important when you buy a computer?

I think #1,2 are right, but #3 is not right. Am I right?

Comment: Why add all those extra words? Are you trying to work on connecting clauses? Well, here's the thing..."What's the thing" is informal, not specific, and we have to wait a few more words to find out what you are talking about. Perhaps you are studying how to join clauses in a sentence? You do have some problems there.

Comment: "What's the most important thing to consider when purchasing a computer?" (11 words)

Answer (score -1):

Your sentences are understandable, but at the same time awkward and verbose (too many words).

**So important** is not equivalent to **most important**, so immediately your alternative sentences can not replace your original sentence.  A possibility might be (with the same verbosity)

> What **one** thing you think is so important, that you consider it, when buying a computer?

**One thing** would be equivalent to **most**.

The other concern with the sentences are that you are asking "what is most important" but making it hypothetical ( **would** ), unless you are being polite, something more to the point would be

> What **do** you consider *( to be )* most important when buying a computer?

Answer (score -2):

All are incorrect.

One correct option would be:

What the thing you would consider most important when buying a computer?

Comment: "What **is** the most important thing you would.... " But it's still an unnecessarily long question.